# How to create virtual host for laravel 5 project

Tags: apache, wampserver

I'm using Laravel 5 for project development and I trying to configure virtual hots on wampserver.

I have changed httpd-vhost file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin khudadadrs@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "F:/Projects/college/public"
    ServerName www.college.edu
    <Directory "F:/Projects/college/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        # onlineoffline tag - don't remove
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 www.college.edu
```

The problem is, when I navigate to url: `www.college.edu` I'm getting back to the localhost of wampserver not to my project.
I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If a Virtul Hosts definition is incorrect Apache will default to the first defined domain in the httpd-vhost.conf file which should be localhost, for security reasons.

I would also avoid using read TLD's, I tend to use `.dev`

I am assuming you are using the latest WAMPServer, which includes Apache 2.4 so the security syntax has changed from `Allow...` to `Require`

See if this works better:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin khudadadrs@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "F:/Projects/college/public"
    ServerName college.dev
    ServerAlias www.college.dev
    <Directory "F:/Projects/college/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the host file should look like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1  localhost

127.0.0.1 college.dev
::1 college.dev
```